# Android SIP SSL

Tags: android, voip, sip

I'm using the SIP stack in Android 2.3.4 and everything is working nicely.  However, I need the system to use SSL, and have created the following code:

```
        SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder("user","domain");
        builder.setPassword("password");
        builder.setOutboundProxy("sip:IPADDRESS:5061;transport=tls");
        builder.setProtocol("TCP");

        builder.setAutoRegistration(true);
        me = builder.build();

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(Constants.INCOMING_CALL_INTENT);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
        manager.open(me, pi, registrationListener);
```

Unfortunately the TLS bit in the setOutboundProxy() call appears to be doing nothing.  Can anyone suggest how to use SSL with the inbuilt SIP stack?  I don't really want to use pjsip as the app is working as it is, so would require a huge rewrite to use pjsip.

Thanks,
Ed

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK Android's built-in SIP stack does not support SSL/TLS

Comment: There is a issue open for adding support: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=136077

Comment: I have no idea, sorry