# Android native sip based voip client with ssl/tls security?

Tags: android, sip, ssl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android SIP SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294668/android-sip-ssl)

I am a student doing a school project on securing voip calls.

My question is: Can an android voip client application using the android native SIP API be secured at any level(session initiation/media transport) by means of SSL/TLS using only the android API, no external C/C++ libraries and if so, how would I go about doing that?

Any code would be much appreciated.